# double hashing for code signing and verification

Tags: hash, digital-signature, integrity, code-signing

I have environmental constraints where the cyber and safety functions are segregated such that safety operations are handled by one unit and cyber operations such as firewall, HIDS, secure storage etc. are handled by another unit that is sitting on the same local LAN. Only the unit that is handling cyber operations is exposed to the outer world for all external communications.

In this setup, I have USB interface available on the unit that handles all safety features/functions that is used to update the firmware image of both safe-only unit and cyber-only unit.

Considering the current size of binaries is about ~1.5GB in size. I want to move the file via NFS to the cyber-only unit only if the cyber validation (code-signing verification) is successful. But copying the file over NFS/network takes time. So, I have a custom API message which is sent by cyber-only unit to safe-only unit to compute the SHA256 of the new image. This means, I could perform the code signing verification on the file which originally contains the hash of the new package. Similarly, on the other side, I would code-sign the file that contains the hash of the package/image.

Does double hashing in this specific case provide the same assurance as that of having/using single hashing (the hash of the image is directly signed) considering only the cyber-only unit is exposed to the external network?

Comment: Hashing is not a signature it is for integrity and the risks must be defined.

Comment: Unrelated, but NFS is a rather complex protocol, with a large attack surface. Using NFS between *exposed* and *secure* systems may be suboptimal on a security point of view. For your real question you must say what kind of attacks you want to be protected from.